# RabbitMQ - Diff between 'delivery-limit' and 'x-delivery-limit' queue arguments

Tags: rabbitmq

What is the difference between `delivery-limit` and `x-delivery-limit`?

When I set the `x-delivery-limit` as RabbitMQ queue argument I can see it is limiting my message requeue attempts, as I expected, but in the official RabbitMQ documentation I see the usage of `delivery-limit`.

Answer (score 9):

Both are valid settings.

The difference is that `delivery-limit` is a **policy** vs `x-delivery-limit` is a **queue argument**.

The same difference applies to other RabbitMQ settings, for example

- `dead-letter-exchange` is a policy vs `x-dead-letter-exchange` is a queue argument
- `queue-length` is a policy vs `x-queue-length` is a queue argument

A queue argument is prefixed by `x-` and is also referred to as an `x-argument`. The `x` stands for "extra" or "extended" because these arguments extend the mandatory queue settings. Mandatory queue settings are for example the `durable` and `exclusive` properties. `x-arguments` are optional queue settings. `x-arguments` are set by clients when they declare a queue.

That is, to change an `x-argument`, you would need to re-deploy the client, and re-declare the queue. For an existing queue, changing an `x-argument` is not allowed and will result in an `inequivalent arg error` closing the channel.

This is where policies come in handy. They have the following benefits:

1. Policies are applied **dynamically**. Once a queue is declared, policies can change queue settings at run time. Note that not all queue settings can be changed by a policy. For example changing the `x-queue-type` (for example from `classic` queue to `quorum` queue) is not allowed since a queue process and how it stores messages cannot just be changed dynamically once it has been created. However, most queue settings (including `delivery-limit`) can be changed dynamically via a policy.
2. Policies can be applied to **groups** of queues (and groups of exchanges). A queue argument can only be applied to a single queue.

In general, it's good practice to use a policy instead of queue argument where possible because policies are more flexible.

More in the official docs: https://www.rabbitmq.com/parameters.html#why-policies-exist

Comment: Amazing man! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that `delivery-limit` is just name for header value `x-delivery-limit`. You can find in RabbitMQ UI for queue arguments.

There is a [blog post](https://blog.rabbitmq.com/posts/2020/04/rabbitmq-gets-an-ha-upgrade/) from RabbitMQ with screenshots (Fig 9. Quorum queue arguments) where they are using `x-delivery-limit` header which works only with quorum queues ([feature matrix](https://www.rabbitmq.com/quorum-queues.html#feature-matrix))

UPD: in according with [this screenshot](https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-f8RIcA_tS0E/XoG5npp1YsI/AAAAAAAAE-c/H-C-GN2YVFM2hROgd5KiP3RxPioXAPPggCLcBGAsYHQ/s1600/Capture.PNG) `x-delivery-limit` is a part of queue features however `delivery-limit` is a part of policy definition applied to this queue. Check [this article](https://dradoaica.blogspot.com/2020/03/poison-message-handling-rabbitmq.html) for more details.